# Running Windows start.exe using Process

Tags: c#, command-line

I was installing an MSI package using `Process` with this command:

```
msiexec.exe /norestart /qn /l*v! mylog.log /i package.msi
```

With this C# code:

```
// Start the child process.
Process p = new Process();

// Redirect the output stream of the child process.
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "msiexec";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/norestart /qn /l*v! mylog.log /i package.msi";
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDir;

p.Start();

string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
bool status = p.WaitForExit(timeout);
```

Now I want to run this command but using `start.exe`:

```
start /wait msiexec.exe /norestart /qn /l*v! mylog.log /i package.msi
```

But now when I run this:

```
// Start the child process.
Process p = new Process();

// Redirect the output stream of the child process.
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "start";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/wait msiexec.exe /norestart /qn /l*v! mylog.log /i package.msi";
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDir;

p.Start();

string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
bool status = p.WaitForExit(timeout);
```

But when running it I get an `Exception`: **The system cannot find the file specified**. Also tried setting `UseShellExecute` to `true` but then I get another `Exception`: **The Process object must have the UseShellExecute property set to false in order to redirect IO streams.**

So, is it possible to run the `start` command using C#?

Comment: Have you tried putting the whole path into Filename, and removing the arguments, to make sure your file path is correct.

Comment: i don't think `start` is a program, but something provided by `cmd`.

Comment: Nop, start run a command in a separate command prompt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/c start /wait msiexec.exe /norestart /qn /l*v! mylog.log /i package.msi";
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDir;
```

I think you need to use CMD to execute the start command.